# ERROR in src/app/value/value.component.ts(4,15): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'module'

Tags: angular, visual-studio

When I am doing in Visual Studio Code > Terminal: ng serve
I am receiving that error:

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2019-04-11T08:13:05.077Z
Time: 3917ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 1.93 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 93.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 327 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in src/app/value/value.component.ts(4,15): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'module'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.

i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

I have looked at a similar issue on the stackoverlow but it doesn't help me with this.

I need to compile this code because I want to open my browser: http://localhost:4200/ but it doesn't work there is an error: Cannot GET

Comment: check line 4 of `value.component.ts` is there a typo?

Comment: can you share the source code of `value.component.ts` file, to figure out the error?

Comment: value.component.ts

<code>
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
// tslint:disable-next-line: component-selector
    selector: 'value',
    templateUrl: 'value.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['value.component.scss']
})
export class ValueComponent {

}
<code>

Comment: It's unable to resolve the `module.id`.

Comment: How can I fix that?

Comment: What are you adding `moduleId` for?

Comment: @sudo_kaizen, I am learning Angular and programming and this piece of code was in this file: value.component.ts 
I didn't add this moduleId, I can check where this is connected if you have the idea where?

Comment: What code is on this line `src/app/value/value.component.ts(4,15)`? Can you share that component code or include it in the question? @stardustsky

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this problem also. There's a few things i had to do.

In tsconfig.json change the module

```
"module": "commonjs"
```

Install types node

```
npm i @types/node
```

And in both tsconfig.json and tsconfig.app.json add

```
"types": [
  "node"
]
```

Hope this helps